# Programmatically check for Android OTA system updates

Tags: android, ota

If you go to Settings->About Phone->Check for updates a check is initiated to see if theres any system updates ready for your phone.

How can I do this action programmatically? Further, I am trying to locate where in the Android source code this happens so I can see it fully and understand it better. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 9):

As far as I know, there is no known broadcast, intent or API to do this programmatically.

And it depends on the ROM, and manufacturer.

Sony for example uses a service which, when the wifi is activated, the service checks on Sony's servers for any updates and informs of it.

But when talking about AOSP source, that I do not think happens.

The nearest point of *System update* is found in `packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/DeviceInfoSettings.java`

**Protip**: grep the string "System update" within the `res/values` directory and work backwords and find out where that string variable identifier is used!

***Edit:***

Here's an example broadcast receiver:

```
public class SystemUpdateClass extends BroadcastReceiver{
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
      if (intent.getAction().equals("android.settings.SYSTEM_UPDATE_SETTINGS")){
           Toast.makeText(context, 
                 "Yup! Received a system update broadcast", 
                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
   }
}
```

Here's an example code, from within a activity's `onCreate`:

```
SystemUpdateClass sysUpdate = new SystemUpdateClass();
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction("android.settings.SYSTEM_UPDATE_SETTINGS");
registerReceiver(sysUpdate, filter);
```

Now, what should happen is your app should receive the broadcast, unless I am mistaken that the broadcast is only for system-signed apps... however the rest is left as an exercise :)

Comment: The furthest I've gotten is: <intent android:action="android.settings.SYSTEM_UPDATE_SETTINGS" />  from /packages/apps/Settings/res/xml/device_info_settings.xml  for the system_update_settings key

Comment: I need to find the code for the system activity which has an intent-filter for this action (android.settings.SYSTEM_UPDATE_SETTINGS). Any suggestions how to find it?

Comment: Read my answer again, there is no known broadcast/intent or API available. :) What you can try do is create a small app to register for that broadcast, and see what happens - if your small app receives the broadcast - then do whatever is necessary... and with regards to what I've said, manufacturers use their own implementations...

Comment: So, in other words in AOSP, the android.settings.SYSTEM_UPDATE_SETTINGS action is broadcast but no activity receives it yet? I doubt that because http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.0.4_r1.2/com/android/settings/Utils.java#90  line 101 uses the PackageManager to find all activities that filter the action and like 106 picks the first one thats a system activity. Somewhere, theres a system activity with an intent-filter that filters android.settings.SYSTEM_UPDATE_SETTINGS actions.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, no activity receives that broadcast! As for that Utils source in the grepcode linky, that's for resolving a preference to an activity `updatePreferenceToSpecificActivityOrRemove`, I do not see reference to that intent as you're making out to claim.. challenge for you - do a global grep of the source for that intent string. As I have said, its dependant on the ROM **and** manufacturer, perhaps, in Sony/Samsung/Motorola/HTC uses their own custom broadcast or modified to suit their needs!

Comment: If you follow it deep enough, updatePreferenceToSpecificActivityOrRemove() is used to find the system activity for that action if there is one (otherwise, the Preference wont show in the settings screen). See: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.0.4_r1.2/com/android/settings/DeviceInfoSettings.java#105