# How can an app find out if the user has updated the OS in their device

Tags: java, android

I am trying to build an application in which I need to find out whether the user has updated their Android phone's OS or not.

For example if user's phone has android version 9 and his phone supports android version 11 but he has not updated it then I have to send a notification on his phone that please update your device.
But if his phone doesn't support android version 11 or other new versions then we have to check that till which version his device can support.

Please advise me on how I can do that.

Comment: this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/a/25828574/8283737

Comment: Is this what you are asking?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836609/

Comment: by saving the OS version in Db etc Firebase when user opens app. if( OS value GET CHANGE ) that mean it is changed. save another value next to it.

Comment: I don't think we can help you unless you update the question to explain what you actually mean ... and why your app needs this information.

Comment: For this you have to have access to the firmware API which will tell you if there is an update available or not . There are lots of custom ROM in market so i don't its possible. Update include patches as well not just android version.

Comment: @StephenC I want in my app if user's android device is updated or not. I want to ensure Android device is updated to latest version.

Comment: Now check my question. I have explained it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** - It will be a lot of work.  This is not something that the standard Android APIs support.

---

Here are a couple of approaches that *may* work

### Approach #1

You will need to do is build and maintain a central database of all makes and models of Android phones and the *latest* available OS version for each one.

When your app needs to check if the OS is up to date it does the following:

1. Lookup the device's make and model, and its OS version.  This Q&A explains how to get the current OS version:

   - [How can I check the system version of Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093365)
2. Query the central database (running on your infrastructure) to find out what the latest OS version for the device is.
3. If the user's device is out of date, send the user the notification.

Downside: you will have to assemble the database of devices and OS versions, and **keep it up to date**.  And you will need to pay for the infrastructure that hosts the database and responds to queries.

### Approach #2

For each Android device manufacturer, research how their device firmware works out if there is an update available.  Apparently, this functionality is not standardized.  There are no standard Android APIs that will tell you if the user's device has an OS update available.

Downside: you have a lot of research and (possibly) implementation work to do to support a range of devices.  It will quite possibly entail getting hold of a lot of different types of devices for testing.  (You are unlikely to be able to develop and test on an emulator.